# How to have conditional DataMember in a DataContract?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, datacontractserializer

From the given DataContract I want to display just one XML node for `Benefits`. 
Since, at one time only one of the 3 DataMembers Houses, Cars and Shares will be not null.

```
public class WebAPIModel 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Benefits")]
    public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Benefits")]
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Benefits")]
    public List<Share> Shares { get; set; }     
}
```

(Obviously currently this doesn't work)

How can I make the resultant XML to display just one node `Benefits`?

I tried something like ...

```
    // Since only one property is not null at one time 
    // I thought EmitDefaultValue will do the trick .. but it doesn't
    [DataMember(Name = "Benefits", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

Comment: How would the deserializer know which of the 3 lists to deserialize the `Benefits` element into?

Comment: I was hoping if there is an Attribute which can just ignore the null values !!

Comment: I'm just trying to explain why it won't be possible - it would make it impossible for the deserializer to convert the XML back into an object, as it would be ambiguous about which property to deserialize the `Benefits` element into. Is that clearer?

Comment: In my scenario this never needs to be deserialized. I know what I am asking is not the conventional way of doing it. We've already achieved this by using custom XMLSerializer but its slow. Now, we want to use DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is about serialization, EmitDefaultValue = false should be enough.

For display purposes:

Create a new property called "Benefits", mark it as non-data member, implement getter.

It may have to be of a generic type, common ancestor for Car, Share, etc.
As another option, you might define a new type and generate its instances on the fly when this new property is accessed.

If this approach with new property works for you, also consider implementing it in an extension class, existing in client application only, to reduce server-side clutter.

Comment: EmitDefaultValue = false doesn't work for my scenario. I has to modify the solution but your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Rwiti, if you ended up with a different solution, please post it as the answer to your question. I'm glad Roman's answer helped guide you, but it would be more helpful to know what actually worked.

Comment: I actually didn't find a solution.
I kept on using the `XMLSerializer` 
      public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
if (ShouldSerializeHouse())
   {
    var sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<House>), new XmlRootAttribute("Benifits"));

    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    sr.Serialize(writer, Houses, ns);
   }...
         
            }